# Notifications don't arrive to my email when new answers are posted on my questions in Stack Exchange

Tags: support, notifications, email

I am not getting email notifications when there are any posts to my questions on any Stack Exchange site. I have stackexchange.com, stackoverflow.com and superuser.com added as trusted senders and I bookmark or mark as a favorite the posts I'm interested in. I do get notifications on my iPad's Stack Exchange app. I'd prefer email notifications and don't use an RSS feed.

Some posts have indicated to use the * on a post to mark it as followed but Stack Exchange sites do not show the * any longer (it didn't work anyway).

Comment: You'll get notifications in the inbox at the toolbar in the upper left. Just stay logged in, and you'll see that if you open the homepage next time. The * was replaced by a bookmark symbol, the mechanism is still the same. Following can be done using the _follow_ link under the question. IIRC notifications about post changes won't be sent by eMail at all (I'd not be happy about that BTW).

Comment: I get the inbox notifications and use the bookmark but I don't get email notifications which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @glez the only type of posts you can get to your question are answers. Comments are not posts

Comment: @Luuklag that's something I was not aware of.  I get notifications in the iPad app for all comments.  I'm looking for an email on any and all responses to a question so I know to read it.  I'm not always logged on to the site or using the pad.

Comment: My ISP whitelisted stackexchange.com for emails.  Maybe that was getting in the way.  Unfortunately, I wont know until I have another question and post it.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Luukag, check out my answer here.  I have resolved the problem.  Additionally it looks like comments do trigger a notification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had my email provider white list stackexchange.com and yesterday received an email from a comment made on another question.  White listing has fixed this challenge.

Comment: That is one agressive spam filter

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your email settings are set correctly in your profile?
[Click here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/settings/current) to go to your settings.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I checked that.  Its set to 3 hours.

Comment: okay, curious. I doubt you'll get a notification email from this post now. Seeing you already read your inbox item about it.